# React - Have two components talk to one another

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a `Table` class and a `Menu` class. In the `Menu` class, there is a list of headers from the `Table` class. The `Menu` class has the ability to toggle the visibility of the headers.

How should I approach this? I was thinking about making a third component that encompasses both `Table` and `Class` and facilitates their interactions but I'm not entirely sure how this would look syntactically (sorry, still trying to pick up React).

If there are better ways of approaching this, feel free to answer!

Thanks!

Comment: did you read this? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: Yeah, I did but it doesn't directly address my question. I was wondering how to facilitate the interactions between two different classes?

Comment: It does, but perhaps not directly. Siblings cannot directly talk to eachother, so a parent needs to send props and callback functions down to them so that they communicate through a common ancestor

Comment: Ahh, i see. How do we define parent-children relationships in React? If I render `componentB` in `componentA`, does that mean `componentB` is automatically a child of `componentA`? If so, how would I send variables from `componentB` to `componentA`?

Comment: yes, via callback like in the react docs there.

Answer (score 0):

For two unrelated components (not is a child - parent relationship), it is the best to let them communicate via a kind of eventbus. Facbook itself suggests to use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), but I think in practise [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) is much more simple to learn and more straight foreward.

The general approach is to have a state container for the whole app, which is a single point of information where your components can communicate with each other. If you have some time, this [video tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree?play=yes) seem to be realy helpfull.

In react itself, the communication between components is only between parent and child objects, which can reaches pretty fast its limits or requires weired work-arounds.

Best wishes
Andreas